# Change style with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, height, onmouseover, onmouseout

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #line {
        height: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        background-color: #8e9194;
        position: absolute;
        top: 85%;
        left: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="b1">Click Here</button>
    <script>
      var o = document.getElementById("line");
      document.getElementById("b1").onmouseover = function () {
        o.style.height = "10px";
      };
      document.getElementById("b1").onmouseout = function () {
        o.style.height = "1px";
      };
    </script>
    <div id="line"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can not get this code to work. All i'm trying to do is increase the size of the line on mouseover and get it back to 1px on mouseout.

It would also be nice if theres any way to incorporate some animation into this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), I highly recommend it. If not, drop a comment and I can help with animating with pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also need to add some animation, I'd suggest to use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). It is fast and easy:

```
$(function() {
    $("#b1").hover(function() {
        $("#line").stop().animate({ height: 10 }, 1000);
    }, function() {
        $("#line").stop().animate({ height: 1 }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8YsSd/

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your JavaScript after the elements you're referring to:

```
<button id="b1">Click Here</button>
<div id="line"></div>

<script> var o = document.getElementById("line");
document.getElementById("b1").onmouseover = function ()
{o.style.height="10px";}; document.getElementById("b1").onmouseout =
function () {o.style.height="1px";}; 
</script>
```

Your line `var o = document.getElementById("line");` is being executed prior to the element actually existing.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yw3Ue/)**